# PySerial seems to have a read() limit

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, pyserial

I'm trying to send a large stream of data via serial, and using the PySerial library for my purposes. However, the program freezes whenever I need to read more than somewhere between 10,000 and 15,000 bytes.

`s = ser.read(10000)` works, however `s = ser.read(15000)` does not.

I've tried flushing the buffer, I've tried reading in one byte at a time with a loop, I've even tried opening and closing the port after calls of less bytes to try and receive all the data I'm sending - but no luck.

Any idea how to receive more data without the program freezing?

Comment: have you made sure you actually have 15000 bytes to read? `ser.read` is blocking and only returns if the number of bytes needed is exceeded or if a `'\n'` character is met, or a timeout is reached. Since you're not providing a timeout, this will just block

Comment: @MZ Yes, I'm analyzing the signal between devices and can see a total of 80,000 bytes being sent. Since this post, I added in a timeout and returned the total amount of bytes received, and it is consistently returning a maximum of 14464 bytes. Any thoughts...? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MZ Nevemind! I'm dumb! The issue was on the device end. It was only sending 14464 bytes. Thank you for your help!